# Printing messages from class to ui labels

Tags: qt, printing, label, mouseevent

So I am using the scribble area example from one of the built in examples in QtCreator.

There's this particular method,

```
void ScribbleArea::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if ((event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) && scribbling){
        drawLineTo(event->pos());
        qDebug()<<printPos(event->pos());

    }
}
```

In which I edited it a bit to print out the x,y coordinates in the console, which works perfectly.

```
QString ScribbleArea::printPos(QPoint p)
{
    QString temp = "X is "+QString::number(p.x())+", Y is "+QString::number(p.y());
    return temp;
}
```

But the problem lies here, when I want to print out the messages in the labels of my ui, such that upon moving, the label will update with the current coordinates, instead of printing to the console, like this.

```
ui->label->setText();
```

So the question is how do I link the mouseMoveEvent to my label, which belongs to 2 different classes, as I do not think that I can link the messages to my UI, unless somehow I can reference the UI's label to my mouse event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered that on my own using Signals and Slots
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html